# Flutter Android studio use all Memory

Tags: android-studio, flutter, memory, dart, ram

### Flutter Android studio take all memory

Android studio get all my RAM after few minutes.
I must restart **Dart Analysis** to free the memory.
Restart dart analysis take a moment to restart and during restart the autocomplete don t work correctly so I lost much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens frequently when I checked the "Enable Hot UI" from settings - Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter on Android Studio.  After I unchecked this experimental feature, it does not happen again.

Answer (score 0):

You should clean your flutter project:
go to tools -> flutter -> flutter clean 
or search on it by pressing double shift then type 'flutter clean'
then run your project.

Answer (score -1):

In my case  (8GB iMac)  the problem was Spotlight.

As Android and Flutter contain a huge number of files  my Computer was getting slower and slower.

I changed settings in Spotlight what files to look for AND restricted what directories to access, so now have less problems.

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes Go to settings, Search Spotlight and there you can deselect the one you don't need.